# PHP decrypt passwords from user cd

Tags: php, mysql

I want an inexpensive method to deter my users from sharing passwords with others when accessing my website. Is there a method to store the encrypted password on a cd.  When the user access the website and enters his/her Id, php searches clients drives for the cd with the encrypted password and decrypts the password to compare with MYSQL database password that I set for them.  I will use some software to protect the cd from being copied.  I understand that the user can simply lend the cd to someone, but that will inevitably become an inconvenience for the user to keep doing this.

If there are any other inexpensive suggestions along this line of thinking I would appreciate the help to explore it further.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're missing the really obvious reason this won't be an effective preventative measure.

Comment: In general no - you can't access the end user's CD drive from your web app. At least not without browser plugins to specifically allow this. An RSA-secure-ID device similar to the ones banks give out is probably simplest, or a smartphone implementation of that.

Comment: Exactly how could the PHP code running on your server **EVER** be able to scan a user's computer and figure out where their cdrom is and how to access it?

Comment: I would also like to see the software that prevents copying CD contents.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I don't think any browser offers arbitrary local file access through JavaScript APIs for internet-hosted pages, or even has file-access APIs.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is executed at the server, so there is no way you can do this with php only. You will need to develop a plugin for the browser, or use some kind of extra software.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You need to try that on your own, make your own experiences with the matter and then see that it does not work.

PHP btw is running on the server, not on the client. The only connection between the PHP and the user is some HTTP protocol which can fake you everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Not with PHP. A site running on a web server has no access to the browsing computer's hardware.

Comment: I can't believe there is no simple way to do something like this.

Comment: Isn't letting a web site read your CD a security risk? Under what circumstances would you actually want a web site to do that for you?

Comment: Back in the bad old days of ActiveX, Internet Explorer would allow code downloaded from a web site to run with user-level permissions on your computer. Very Bad People exploited this feature to write malware / viruses. Since lessons were learnt from this painful experience, the vast majority of code running in the browser is "sandboxed".

Comment: I see your point, so how do I deter password sharing, not everyone has a cell phone lol.

Comment: You don't. You might consider allowing logging in only from a single IP address at a time (after logging in from a new IP the session in the old IP gets automatically logged out). If only one person using the same account can be logged in at the same time, it's more convenient to get another account.

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing some two-factor authentication (something I know + something I have).

Check out Google's "[2-step](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/)" verification, whereby they send a verification code via text message to your cell phone that is required to login, in addition to your username and password.

In this case, the cell phone is the "something I have". Users would have to share cell phones or be bothered to provide the verification code.

Comment: Ups SMS to email gateway or even displaying those SMS messages publicly. How come? That two-way is good for the user, not the server.

Comment: I feel like I have been bashed :) No No No, sorry.

Comment: @hakre, I hadn't considered an SMS to email gateway. Anyway, maybe Google two factor isn't the answer, but some level of two factor could be. There's always the dongle. :)